# Uniform distribution function allows for probabilities greater than 1?

Tags: probability

I have been learning about probability and I am having trouble with the uniform distribution function. I learned that a PDF $f(x)$ gives the probability that $x$ happens. However, if I said that $f(x)$ is a uniform distribution function over the interval $[0,1/2]$ then $f(x)=2$ for some values, which is impossible because $f(x)$ is supposed to be a probability.

If it is not a probability, then why can we use this PDF to calculate probabilities?

Comment: That's not what a probability density function.  The integral over the ranges of x gives the probability that x falls within that range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Probability *Denisity* Function (pdf) of a Continuous Random Variable, is the differential of the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF), with respect to the Random Variable.

$$f_X(x) = \frac{\mathrm d~}{\mathrm d x}F_X(x)$$

As the CDF is a Measure of Probability (Mass), it must have all the properties required of such: including $F_X(x)\in[0;1]$, as well as being increasing and right continuous, *et cetera*.

Because the pdf is the differential of such a function, it is "merely" required to be non-negative.   (Well, also to integrate to $1$ over the entire support interval, et cetera.)

---

cf: The mass of any part of a 1kg block of metal cannot exceed $1\text{kg}$, but the density at any point can exceed $1\text{kg$\cdotp$m$^{-3}$}$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is a probability density function, not the probability itself. That is, the probability $P(x\leq \xi)$ is not $f(\xi)$; it's (in this case) $\int_0^\xi dx\,f(x).$

Answer (score 0):

Of course, for a continuous distribution, the probability that $X=x$ is zero (there are no point masses).

A better way to think of the probability density function $f_X$ is that, for very small $\Delta x$, one has
$$\Pr(X\in[x,x+\Delta x])\approx f_X(x)\Delta x$$

(Since the interval is tiny, it doesn't matter at which point $x$ in the interval you choose to evaluate $f_X$ -- the result is about the same, and is only an approximation anyway.)

Comment: So if PDF's are not actual probabilities and I should not think of them that way. Would I have the same problem with PMFs? Or ar PMFs actual probabilities?

Comment: @GuachoPerez A pmf is a probability *mass* function; it is a measure of probability at points in a discretely distributed random variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main confusion comes from this sentence:

> $f(x) = 2$ for some values, which is impossible because $f(x)$ is supposed to be a probability

You're right that $f$ describes a probability. However, $f$ is a *density* function. Think of it like describing the density of a meter-long steel rod; maybe the rod is super light except for a one-centimeter stretch that's really heavy, but the rod is still only 1kg. The rod can be really, really heavy *per-inch*, but it can still weigh 1kg total. Same thing with $f$ and other probability density functions.

Comment: So I should not think of $f$ as a probability per se, but rather as an actual density of probabilities? Does the same apply for a PMF?

Comment: Yup. The difference is that, for a PMF, you weight each point as "one", and in a PDF, you weight each interval/"area" by its measure. Really, a PMF is a PDF with each point having equal measure.

Comment: No.  A PMF is a Probability *Mass* Function.  A PDF is a Probability *Density* Function.  A probability mass *can* not exceed $1$, though a probability density *may*.

Comment: A PMF is, measure-theoretically, a PDF using the counting measure. Each point is weighted equally because the underlying measure just counts the number of elements in the (finite) set.